# How does tidymodels initial_split function deal with a strata variable that is continuous?

Tags: tidymodels

Using the R dataset diamonds, I was wondering how the initial_split function stratifies the continuous variable "x" in order to a create test and training set? ie initial_split(diamonds, probability=0.8, strata=x).
I had read that the continuous data "x" is separated sequentially into bins, but I couldn't find out how many bins, or if the number of bins could be set by the user?

Answer (score 3):

The number of breaks used by [initial_split()](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/initial_split.html) when stratifying against a continuous variable is specified by the `breaks` argument. `breaks` defaults to 4 bins.

```r
library(rsample)
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")

initial_split(diamonds, strata = x, breaks = 4)
#> <Analysis/Assess/Total>
#> <40453/13487/53940>
```

What is happening under the hood is that `make_strata()` is used to create a factor variable that is then for stratification. The factor variable will be created based on percentiles to ensure that the strata are of roughly uniform size.

```r
table(make_strata(diamonds$x, breaks = 4))
#> 
#>    [0,4.71]  (4.71,5.7]  (5.7,6.54] (6.54,10.7] 
#>       13521       13665       13379       13375

table(make_strata(diamonds$x, breaks = 10))
#> 
#>    [0,4.36] (4.36,4.54] (4.54,4.82] (4.82,5.23]  (5.23,5.7]  (5.7,6.08] 
#>        5774        5032        5394        5463        5523        5186 
#> (6.08,6.42]  (6.42,6.7]  (6.7,7.31] (7.31,10.7] 
#>        5407        5429        5458        5274
```